# How to load in HTML elements instead of text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to javascript and trying to learn. 
I've written out this code and I am trying to get it to load in videos. 
When I load the page it is showing the  related tags as text.
I have provided a plunker below.

```
 $('.video-label').text($video.get(0).outerHTML);
```

I think it is the '.text' in this line that is appending the text to a p tag in the html?

Instead I would like this data that is collected from the array to write out as html elements that will be loaded in the page so that the  tags will play the source that is loaded in

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCb1LWVvJDvfZRgad2zR?p=preview)

What will I have to change in the html and js to stop text and load in the videos instead?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: It might be worth reading the API documentation for the method: [`text()`](http://api.jQuery.com/text/).

Comment: @DavidThomas I read the documentation on .text and it didn't direct me to using .html, which i've found out is what I am looking for. 
I still can't get the videos to load in properly as elements even after applying the change. 
shouldn't $(".video-label").html($video.get(0).outerHTML);
pass in the html to load in instantly?

Comment: If using the `text()` method retrieved the correct/expected string of HTML, then yes (albeit 'instantly' is perhaps not necessarily correct), I'd imagine so. But, as shown in my answer, I think there's a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding HTML is done with `.html()` instead of `.text`.

```
$(".video-label").html($video.get(0).outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks patrick, that looks like what I'm missing. 
When I change this out, I don't see anything load in, i'm guessing something needs to be changed with the HTML as well?

Comment: all depends on what you're getting back... you can debug what you put in using the browser's console: window.console&&console.log($view.get(0).outerHTML) would show the html for instance. inspecting the element to see what is written to it could also shed some light on the matter

Comment: I'm not getting anything back in my console as it's showing up blank, when I tried entering in the code you've given it says that $view is not defined

Comment: It should be pretty straight forward I thought.. as long as its passing in as an html element rather than .text it should work shouldn't it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry... programming on my own stuff as well, not paying full attention :)... it should be $video, not $view

Comment: Ah, no worries :) 
I put in the code you've suggested and in the console I am getting  <video loop="" autoplay=""><source type="webm" src="/videos/2.webm"><source type="mp4" src="/videos/2.mp4"></video> Does that mean it is passing this into the html? why isn't it working, that html code should load in the video shouldn;t it?

Comment: If it is loading in <video loop="" and autoplay="">
would that be whats preventing it from working? How can I remove the quotations

Comment: You could try hardcoding the code in a temp file to see if this works

Comment: currently im testing all of this in a temp file

Comment: Here is the plunker if you can figure it out
I put in the console.log code and you can see that everytime the button is clicked it is logging it in the console, I just dont know why its not loading out in the page
http://plnkr.co/edit/Zynp0TBcTo7nQxxIe5UT?p=preview

Comment: the most obvious thing I saw on there is that http://run.plnkr.co/videos/7.webm doesn't exist, so it can never play...

Comment: Hey patrick, I've been testing it at home and have the videos in the correct directory

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to add HTML elements you need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

```
$('.video-label').html($video.get(0).outerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks! That must be what I was missing. When I load in the page though I don't see my videos loaded in. Does anything else needed to be changed with the html?

Answer (score 0):

Given your (apparent) intended result, I'd suggest:

```
$('.video-label')
    // get the child elements:
    .contents()
    // replace them with $video:
    .replaceWith($video)
```

This, obviously, assumes that `$video` references the correct element.

References:

- [`contents()`](http://api.jQuery.com/contents/).
- [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jQuery.com/replaceWith/).

Comment: Thanks for the help David. 
I've tried putting this in, and it really hasn't changed anything. Im not even really sure what this is supposed to do.. 
Sorry I am still trying to learn and I thought I was really close to getting this to work when I was getting the right string back. But after switching .text to .html I am not seeing the videos load in at all into the page, I have added in window.console&&console.log($video.get(0).outerHTML) and the console is returning <video loop="" autoplay=""><source type="webm" src="/videos/2.webm"><source type="mp4" src="/videos/2.mp4"></video>